# Where and how can I view a generated database query

Tags: strapi

I have a small question:
Where and how can I view a generated database query, via "Debug" or "Strapi.log.info(...)"?

Many greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can in you `config/environments/development/database.json` file into the `options` object add the following `"debug": true`

You will be able to see all the database requests.

eg. for a SQLite database connection

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "bookshelf",
      "settings": {
        "client": "sqlite",
        "filename": ".tmp/data.db"
      },
      "options": {
        "useNullAsDefault": true,
        "debug": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```